# About substring testing in Java

Tags: java

I'm writing some codes that test if there is "xx" in a string. For instance, doubleX("aaxxbb") should return true, and doubleX("axabb") should return false.

Here is my code:

```
private static boolean doubleX(String str) {
  for(int i=0;i<str.length()-1;i++){
      System.out.println(str.substring(i,i+2));
      if(str.substring(i,i+2) == "xx") return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Why does doubleX("aaxxbb") return false?

Comment: Use the .equals() method to compare strings.

Comment: are you allowed to used `.indexOf()` [see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String) ]

Comment: or even `.contains()`

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `.equals` instead of `==`. For more information, follow the duplication message.

```
return str.contains("xx");
```

Is a lot clearer though.

Answer (score 1):

You should understand the difference between == and equals: the first one compares references, the second compares actual values.

Your code is wildly inefficient.

I'd try something like this:

```
private static boolean doubleX(String str) {
    return (str.indexOf("xx") != -1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `equals()` for checking the content of a String to another rather than `==`. `==` checks for reference equality.

```
private static boolean doubleX(String str) {
        for(int i=0;i<str.length()-1;i++){
            System.out.println(str.substring(i,i+2));
            if(str.substring(i,i+2).equals("xx")) return true;
        }
        return false;
      }
```

Even you can directly code like:

```
private static boolean doubleX(String str) {
        return str.contains("xx");
      }
```